# Is it possible to use data from one sub-query inside another in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I've been banging my head on a wall for a few hours now trying to figure out how to do this properly within a single query. This is the fruits of quite a bit of searching to boot.

```
UPDATE invoices inv INNER JOIN (
 SELECT * 
FROM (

SELECT invoice_id, SUM( invoice_items.tax1_value ) AS tax1_total, SUM( invoice_items.tax2_value ) AS tax2_total, SUM( invoice_items.extended_profit ) AS total_profit, SUM( invoice_items.extended_cost ) AS total_cost, SUM( invoice_items.extended ) AS subtotal, SUM( invoice_items.discount_value ) AS discount
FROM invoice_items
GROUP BY invoice_id
) AS totals
WHERE `invoice_id` = '1001')tot ON inv.invoice_id = tot.invoice_id
SET inv.tax1_total = tot.tax1_total,
inv.tax2_total = tot.tax2_total,
inv.total_profit = tot.total_profit,
inv.total_cost = tot.total_cost,
inv.subtotal = tot.subtotal,
inv.discount = tot.discount,
inv.total = ( tot.subtotal + tot.tax1_total + tot.tax2_total ) ,
inv.subtotal = tot.subtotal WHERE inv.invoice_id = '1001';

UPDATE invoices SET due = ( total - received ) WHERE invoice_id =1001
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide some more background on what problem you are actually trying to solve?  It's not clear from the code what your intent is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can plug in the expression for `total` and use that for the update:

```
UPDATE invoices inv INNER JOIN
       (SELECT invoice_id, SUM( invoice_items.tax1_value ) AS tax1_total,
                SUM( invoice_items.tax2_value ) AS tax2_total,
                SUM( invoice_items.extended_profit ) AS total_profit,
                SUM( invoice_items.extended_cost ) AS total_cost,
                SUM( invoice_items.extended ) AS subtotal,
                SUM( invoice_items.discount_value ) AS discount
       FROM invoice_items
       WHERE `invoice_id` = '1001'
       GROUP BY invoice_id
      ) AS tot
      ON inv.invoice_id = tot.invoice_id
SET inv.tax1_total = tot.tax1_total,
    inv.tax2_total = tot.tax2_total,
    inv.total_profit = tot.total_profit,
    inv.total_cost = tot.total_cost,
    inv.subtotal = tot.subtotal,
    inv.discount = tot.discount,
    inv.total = ( tot.subtotal + tot.tax1_total + tot.tax2_total ) ,
    inv.subtotal = tot.subtotal,
    inv.due = ( tot.subtotal + tot.tax1_total + tot.tax2_total ) - inv.received
WHERE inv.invoice_id = '1001';
```

The above query also removes the unnecessary subquery in the `join`.  As a note, the final `where` is also unnecessary because the `join` does the same filtering.

Comment: It amazes me how much faster your query runs than my original to boot.

Comment: @Nate . . . MySQL materializes subqueries.  So, your original query had to summarize the entire `invoice_items` table before selecting the one row.  I imagine this is most of the performance improvement.